# Parsing XML in Pure C

Tags: c, xml

What is the preferred library for parsing XML data in Pure C?

Comment: the libraries sugested are good but I have created my own simple xml parser after a few problems with Expat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The canonical XML parsing library for C is [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Comment: Which is released under a [very liberal license](http://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/Copyright). It's also extremely portable and well tested.

Answer (score 5):

Two popular choices are [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) and [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of libraries for multiple languages, including C:

http://www.xml.com/pub/rg/XML_Parsers

Answer (score 1):

Not 'the preferred library', but there's also http://www.minixml.org/.

> Mini-XML is a small XML library that
>   you can use to read and write XML and
>   XML-like data files in your
>   application without requiring large
>   non-standard libraries. Mini-XML only
>   requires an ANSI C compatible compiler
>   (GCC works, as do most vendors' ANSI C
>   compilers) and a 'make' program.
>
> Mini-XML supports reading of UTF-8 and
>   UTF-16 and writing of UTF-8 encoded
>   XML files and strings. Data is stored
>   in a linked-list tree structure,
>   preserving the XML data hierarchy, and
>   arbitrary element names, attributes,
>   and attribute values are supported
>   with no preset limits, just available
>   memory.

Answer (score 0):

VTD-XML is the one you should look into, if you want a combination of ease of use, performane and efficiency

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [miniML-Parser](https://github.com/kiishor/miniML-Parser), a simple and tiny XML parser library in C. It is specifically developed for embedded applications in mind.

- It is extremely easy to use: You need to call only one API to parse your XML data
- It has a very small footprint: The parser uses only 1.8 kB1 of code memory. Hence, you can use it in very small embedded applications.
- It is a validating XML parser.
- It also extracts the content of XML data and converts it to its specified data type.
- It comes with a tool to generate the source code from XML schema file, instead of manually writing XML tree structure in C.

> Disclosure: I'm author of this miniML-Parser