# XML library for C

Tags: c, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing XML in Pure C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846568/parsing-xml-in-pure-c)

Which is the best XML Library for C?

Features I am looking out for are

1) Good Support in the form of tutorials and active mailing list.
2) Easy to develop.
3) *Portability* for Windows, Linux, Mac.
4) I need to do parsing, validating and writing of simple XML Files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/)** should do the trick.